# passing in enum values into jquery grid filter

Tags: jquery, grails, enums, grid

this seems really easy but have not been able to do it.

Currently I have an enum:

```
enum LocationCodes{
  USA(3), Canada(4), Carribean(5), USPacific(6)
  NANPCodeGroup(int value) {this.value = value}
  private final int value
  public int value() {return value}
}
```

And I have a jquery grid in my gsp that has a dropdown for searching

```
        <!-- table tag will hold our grid -->
        <table id="customer_list" class="scroll jqTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
        <!-- pager will hold our paginator -->
        <div id="customer_list_pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
        /* when the page has finished loading.. execute the follow */
        $(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#customer_list").jqGrid({
              url:'jq_customer_list',
              datatype: "json",
              colNames:['customer','location','id'],
              colModel:[
                {name:'customer'},
                {name:'location',stype:'select', searchoptions:{value:':All;USA:USA;Canada:Canada;Carribean:Carribean;USPacific:USPacific;'}},
                {name:'id', hidden:true}
              ],
              rowNum:2,
              rowList:[1,2,3,4],
              pager: jQuery('#customer_list_pager'),
              viewrecords: true,
              gridview: true
            });
            $("#customer_list").jqGrid('filterToolbar',{autosearch:true});
        });
        </script>
```

For the location I would like to put in the enum values.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Comment: adding bounty for working solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should give the list of enums separated by ';'

```
${LocationCodes?.values()?.collect{it.toString() + ':' + it.toString()}?.join(';')}
```

So you can try something like this:

```
searchoptions: {
    value: ":All;${LocationCodes?.values()?.collect{it.toString() + ':' + it.toString()}?.join(';')}" 
}
```

Double check the escaping of quotes, but it should work. :)

Comment: Added code, got error expecting '}', found ')' @ line 44, column 186.
   ring() + ':' + it.toString() })

When there that last parenthese does not exist in my code...so weird

Comment: Just tried to console.log(":All;${LocationCodes?.values()?.collect{it.toString() + ':' + it.toString()}?.join(';')}") this and it works quite good. Try it yourself, double check it. :)

Comment: Dunno dude, in my project (different enum but same structure/behaviour) it works. Can you please share a snippet with the js block with the code (applying these changes) and the stacktrace that you get? It would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work? (assuming it's a GSP)

```
{ name:'location',
  stype:'select',
  searchoptions:{ value:'":All;${LocationCodes.values().collect { "$it:${it.value()}" }.join(';')};"'}},
```

That *should* give you

```
':All;USA:3,Canada:4,Carribean:5,USPacific:6;'
```

But I've not tested it :-/

Comment: Close, I am getting an error expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway collect { "$it:${it.value() })

Comment: @Badmiral Sure you copied it correctly?  That seems to be missing the closing `"` char...

Comment: @Badmiral Can you try: `'":All;${LocationCodes.values().collect { [ it, it.value() ] }*.join( ':' ).join(';')};"'` It might be the String inside a String causing the issue?

Comment: tried that similar error, with  expecting '}', found ')', no idea why it is coming up